# Postgressql: copy data from prod database to dev database for some tables only

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump, dbeaver

I've been tasked to copy some tables from the prod environment to the dev environment. These tables obviously exclude any user/account related tables. The databases are in separate RDS instances. The databases are `datawarehouse_production` and `datawarehouse_development`.

The issue I'm current facing is that I'm using DBeaver and am able to create DB dumps so for example, I create a dump for table 'responses' now when I try to use that dump and restore it to the dev environment, I get an error that says:

```
pg_restore: error: could not execute query: ERROR:  must be owner of relation responses

Command was: ALTER TABLE public.responses OWNER TO datawarehouse_production;
```

I can't even open the bloody dump files because they're binary. Here's what the dump file looks like:
[image]

I wish to get rid of those queries that do for example: `Drop database datawarehouse_production` as the database I want to copy data to is datawarehouse_development.

I'm aware DBeaver has a transfer data feature but that is incredibly slow (50 mins for 20,000 rows). I've used it for smaller tables however the data I need to copy are 11 million rows.

I've also tried exporting the data to CSV from prod tables then loading them into dev tables however it's just as slow.

**EDIT:** After adding the --data-only flag:
[image]

**EDIT 2:** Finally managed to make things work. Here's the backup settings window:
[image]

And when restoring the dump, had to add `--data-only` flag in the extra command flags field!

Comment: Your database dump contains a lot of information required to replicate the exact state of the dumped tables, which includes permission-setting queries like the one that's exploding. Try `pg_restore --data-only` to ignore those parts. Alternatively, a tool like https://github.com/ankane/pgsync might be an option.

Comment: Okay I'll try that

Comment: Please check my edit for the latest error. Thanks!

Comment: Any chance you altered the dump file when trying to open it and inspect it? Not much out there on Google for that error message.

Comment: I did some googling and found a suggestion to change the format of the dump file to TAR instead of CUSTOM in the DBeaver window when creating a dump. I did that and along with the `--data-only` flag, the restore worked! You may add an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your database dump contains a lot of information required to replicate the exact state of the dumped tables, which includes permission-setting queries like the one that's exploding. If you already have the schema locally and don't want to replicate those sorts of things, try `pg_restore --data-only` to just load the data into your existing schema.